# How to get text "ONLY ONCE" between <option> some value</option> tags using jquery or java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem:
when the user click on multiple check boxes the text value from the option tags copied multiple times in the item list.

Let There are two option list .
list 1 and list 2

from list 1 and list 2 i need the text value only once from the option tags.

Please see My fiddle for better understanding.

```
<p>list 1</p>
 <select >
 <option id="item" value="amna">Volvo</option>
 <option  id="item" value="sara">Saab</option>
 <option id="item" value="jhon">Opel</option>
 <option id="item" value="khubab">Audi</option>
```

```
 <p>list 2</p>
 <select >
  <option id="item" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option  id="item" value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option id="item" value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option id="item" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/75/)

Thanks in advance and do not cast vote down to my question as i am new here.Please edit my question if you think it is ambiguous.

Fiddle Example will be appreciated.

Comment: In HTML, Identifiers must be unique, You mustn't use `id="item"`multiple times

Comment: i will make it correct after getting answer

Comment: I can't see anything getting duplicated in your fiddle

Comment: There is no duplications

Comment: use class instead of id

Comment: you are adding your selected option using a loop, add it only once `values.each(function(){
     list.append( "<li>" + $(this).next().html() + "</li>");
    });
    list.append( "<li>" +optionText+ "</li>" );`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/82/ this is not exactely what you asked for @waqas, but it probably works well for your case.

Comment: I need text values from two selection list.And i need exactly like this http://jsfiddle.net/waqasadil/7HQDK/84/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all change all id's to classes you cannot use multiple id's with same name.**

Every time you are appending an extra `li` from your `select tag` which is wrong.

Here is your required answer,

```js
function addToList( values, optionText,optionText2 ) {
    var list = $( "#grocery-list ul" );
    list.empty();
    values.each(function(){
     list.append( "<li>" + $(this).next().html() + " <a class='delete_li'> (x)</a> </li>" );
    });
    list.append( "<li>" + optionText + " <a class='delete_li'>(x)</a> </li>" );
    list.append( "<li>" + optionText2 + " <a class='delete_li'>(x)</a> </li>" );
};

$('body').on('click', '.delete_li', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "input:checked" ).effect( "transfer", {
        to: "#grocery-list ul",
        complete: function() {
         var optionText = $('.first_select :selected').val();
          var optionText2 = $('.second_select :selected').val();
          console.log(optionText)
            addToList( $( "input:checked" ), optionText,optionText2 );
        }
    });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: 300px;
}

input {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#grocery-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0 1em 0em 1em;
}

#grocery-list h3 {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

.ui-effects-transfer {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<style href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="grocery-list">
 <h3>Item List</h3>
 <ul>
  <li class="empty">Empty</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Add Item</legend>
  <label for="item">Item:</label><br>
  <input class="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle"  value="bike"><label>I have a bike</label> 
   <br>
      <input class="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="cycle" ><label>I have a bicycle </label>
     <br>
          <input class="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="aeroplane" ><label>I have a aeroplane </label>
       <br>
              <input class="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"><label>I have a car</label><br>
   <select class="first_select">
  <option class="item" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option  class="item" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option class="item" value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option class="item" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><br>
<select class="second_select">
  <option class="item" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option  class="item" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option class="item" value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option class="item" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><br>
        
         <button>Add</button>
        </fieldset>
       </form>
```

Pls run this code and check,

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/93/)

Comment: I need to option list instead of one.

Comment: you need multiple select of cars?

Comment: I need multiple select from two different selection tag

Comment: Here is example of two option list  http://jsfiddle.net/waqasadil/7HQDK/84/

Comment: you have 4 cars, why do you need only two select boxes?

Comment: Updated both my ans and fiddle, pls check for 2 select boxes.

Comment: check my ans, its the same.

Comment: I want a cross (x) sign on each item in item list so each item can b deleted separately .....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124197/discussion-between-sravan-and-waqas-adil).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was to add the car name inside of the each loop which added it once per selected checkbox.

Check this fiddle:

```js
$("button").button();

function addToList(values, optionText) {
  var list = $("#grocery-list ul");
  list.empty();
  values.each(function() {
    list.append("<li>" + $(this).next().html() + "</li>");
  });
  list.append("<li>" + optionText + "</li>");
};

$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("input:checked").effect("transfer", {
    to: "#grocery-list ul",
    complete: function() {
      var optionText = $('select :selected').val();
      addToList($("input:checked"), optionText);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: 300px;
}
input {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
#grocery-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0 1em 0em 1em;
}
#grocery-list h3 {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.ui-effects-transfer {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="grocery-list">
  <h3>Item List</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="empty">Empty</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Add Item</legend>
    <label for="item">Item:</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="bike">
    <label>I have a bike</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="cycle">
    <label>I have a bicycle</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="aeroplane">
    <label>I have a aeroplane</label>
    <br>
    <input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">
    <label>I have a car</label>
    <br>
    <select>
      <option id="item" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option id="item" value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option id="item" value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option id="item" value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <button>Add</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: i need two option list instead of one.